# 2 way communication Python socket

Tags: python, python-2.x, json, http, socket

I'm trying to create a 2 way communication socket in python. The socket will listen for connections from the client until it gets the data formatted in string like this: 'PHONENUMBER|STATUS'. I will need to split that and convert it to json which will be sent via http request to a web api. When the api receives, it will handle the request and then it will return a status in json format which I will convert to string to return it to the client as string. I would like to have a professional opinion about my code and any additional ideas to what I would like to achieve would be appreciated.

```
import socket
import json
import requests
import httplib

HOST= '127.0.0.1'
PORT= 80

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Bind to adress

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print ("Socket bound.")

#Start listening
s.listen(10)
print ("Socket Listening")

conn, addr = s.accept()
url = 'http://www.google.com'
while True:
      data = conn.recv(1024)

      dictionary = dict(item.split("|") for item in data .split(";"))

      json = json.dumps(dictionary, ensure_ascii=False)

      r = requests.get(url, data=json)

 print r.text
```

Comment: Hi Sam, you are right, I posted this on Stackoverflow and it was formatted in the wrong way. I don't need the first split, that was my error, since the dictionary takes item and split it himself. the print at the end should not be like that. I explained what I intend to do, I added the code just as a reference or idea of what Im trying to achieve. I expect to have some sort of idea besides my own on how to implement my goal. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I changed my comment to an "answer".

Comment: @AlexDev4Life You should post a [**working** piece of code at least](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the errors are minor buy you should still fix them.

Comment: Hi, Sorry everyone, I made some fixes on the code to make it clear. I posted this last night really quick. Thanks

Comment: hi, in python indentation is significant.  Your last line `print r.text` needs to be indented same as the previous lines with six spaces (which is an unusual indent level, by the way - I suggest 4 or 8 spaces, or one tab).  If this code works now, as you suggest, please provide an example session using e.g. telnet or a test program: what data you send to it, and what data you expect it to send back after talking to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not compile, and has many bugs. Can you fix the errors in it?

`url- =` is a syntax error.

I don't recommend calling a variable `split` when you are using a method `split`, it's confusing.

You did not use that variable named `split`.

You did not define a variable `message`.

`print 'r.text'` should I suppose be `print r.text`.

I'm not sure about `data = conn.recv(1024)`, what will happen if a request is longer than 1024 bytes?

This code needs to be debugged, it is not ready for code review. But it seems like a nice idea, and structurally okay, a good start.  I could help you debug it and get it working if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I formatted the text, it was all messed up. Now  it can be reviewed